# Why is that REGEX not working?

Tags: regex

```
.*?(?<=(?:FROM|JOIN))\s*(.*?)\s*(?=(?:ON|JOIN|WHERE|LIMIT|GROUP|ORDER|\(|;))
```

INPUT:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM table1, table2 WHERE bla,bla GROUP BY bla ORDER bla LIMIT bla) tableTmp UNION SELECT * FROM table3,table4 WHERE bla;
```

http://regex101.com/r/cE7tT8

I must be missing something, last part is not eaten by the wildcard...
It outputs: "table1, table2table3,table4WHERE bla;"

I tried combinations with '$' but either it does not match anything or either it leaves intact the last part

Comment: What do you want to achieve ?

Comment: ^ Create DBMS with single regex? Well, it won't work, because SQL is not the thing which that can be handled with single regex.

Comment: I'd like to extract table names from queries the most accurately possible, though I don't mind if it's not totally clean as long as it saves up some non meaningful (non tables) info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the link you provide does several substitutions.  It makes three matches and does subs for each of them. You can see this by substituting with `|\0|` instead of your `\1`.

So the problem is that you have junk left over at the end after all these have been matched.  A solution is to have the match consume characters up to the beginning of relevant portions of the next match.

This can be done by using negative lookahead. - Add `(.(?!SELECT))*` to the end of your regexp;

```
.*?(?<=(?:FROM|JOIN))\s*(.*?)\s*(?=(?:ON|JOIN|WHERE|LIMIT|GROUP|ORDER|\(|;))(.(?!SELECT))*
```